# What equipment is required to replace the DVD-ROM with a hard disk drive?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I just bought a Samsung ATIV Book 2 (http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/pc-peripherals/notebook-computers/laptops/NP270E5G-K03UK) yesterday and the salesperson said if I would like to replace the DVD-ROM with an additional hard disk drive, I just need to install a dock to contain the HDD.

This is obviously some type of interface, but after searching on the web, I still have no idea what that required hardware is.  Could someone describe it?

Comment: This question has been downvoted and flagged as off-topic (request for a hardware purchase recommendation).  However, I think this is really more of a hardware interfacing question.

Comment: i'd have thought this would be on topic, it's not a hardware purchase recommensation question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a HDD caddy, which looks like these:

[image: Hard drive caddy]

One can be obtained from eBay, Amazon, or even some local PC/hobby stores.

Comment: oh yes, this is what I need.

Comment: Is the scorpion really necessary for installation?

Comment: that was merely a informational posting any similar  should work

Comment: @Mokubai of course yes. It is possible you miss that the HDD is a _Western Digital __[Scorpio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Digital#2000s)__ Blue_? :-)